# Terminology: What are the labels associated with a share called?

Tags: stocks, terminology

When I look up share information, e.g. [here](https://www.google.co.uk/finance?client=ob&q=NASDAQ%3aGOOG), I get at least three pieces of information:

- The share price (e.g. $681.79)
- The company name associated with the share (e.g. Google Inc)
- The shorthand version of the company name idenfitying the stock (e.g. NASDAQ:GOOG)

What are the technical terms for the last two labels? Is it "stock name", "stock symbol", "stock denomination", etc.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the first one is literally a company name, then 'company name' is fine. However, companies can issue shares more than once, and those shares might be traded separately, so you could have 'Google ordinary', 'Google preference', 'Google ordinary issue B'. Seeing the name spelled out in full like this isn't as common as just the company name, but I'd normally see it referred to as 'display name'.

The second one is 'symbol', 'ticker', 'ID', and others. Globally, there are many incompatible ways of referring to a stock, depending on where it's listed (companies can have dual listings, and different exchanges have different conventions), and who's referring to it (Bloomberg and Reuters have different sets of IDs, with no predictable mapping between them). So there's no one shorthand name, and the word you use depends on the context. However, 'symbol' or 'ticker' is normally fine.